# Overwriting list value

Tags: c#

I'm working on this code that gets the user to make an account and then store that account in a list, the problem I currently have is that the list overwrites the item every time I try to add a new one.

Essentially the list needs be able to make an endless amount of "accounts" each which can be differentiated and added to the list. I'm still very new to c# and do not quite understand why it is being overwritten, any clarity would be appreciated.

EDIT: I want to be able to call CreateAccount() so that a user can create a fresh item that will be added onto the list, PrintAccount() only serves to show me what is on the list, the main issue I am having is getting the system to recognize the list and add items properly onto it. I just want to be able to call a method that can create an account and add it onto a list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Assignment_List_Test
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

        AccountView Accounts = new AccountView()
        {
            AccountList = new List<Account>()
        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateAccount();
            PrintAccounts();
        }
        static void CreateAccount()
        {
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string userNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Email: ");
            string userEmailInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string userPasswordInput = Console.ReadLine();

            var AccName = new Account
            {
                Username = userNameInput,
                UserEmail = userEmailInput,
                UserPassword = userPasswordInput
            };

            Accounts.AccountList.Add(AccName);
        }
        static void PrintAccounts()
        {
            foreach (var Account in Accounts.AccountList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}, UserEmail: {1}, UserPassword: ${2}", Account.Username, Account.UserEmail, Account.UserPassword);
            }
        }
    }
    public class AccountView
    {
        public List<Account> AccountList { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: _"every time I try to add a new one"_ You're currently only adding one account to the list. You should show us _how_ you're adding multiple accounts so we can tell you what's wrong with _that_ code. For example, are you calling `PrintAccounts()` multiple times? Note that in that method, you're always creating a _new_ instance of `AccountView` and a _new_ list, so you might want to move that to a separate method which is called only once and make `Accounts` a class-level field/property.

Comment: After a second look, I'm not even sure why you have `PrintAccounts()` (or `Main`) inside the `Account` class. An instance of `Account` should probably not know anything about `AccountList`.

Comment: Your main function calls PrintAccounts. It prompts the user and creates a single account. Then it creates an AccountView and creates/sets the account list in that object. It adds the account that was created to that list. Then it walks through all the accounts in that list (i.e., the _one_ you created) and prints it out. Then you reach the end of the function. Since the Account and the AccountView are local to that function, they disappear. How do you want it to behave?

Comment: @Flydog57 I want the function to add a new account every time to a list, It's still a bit of a work in progress do right now the code only adds one, essentially i want PrintAccounts() to just be able to create an account and then add it to an existing list, from the sound of it I have some things in the wrong place and will need to resort through my code.

Comment: @41686d6564 The Idea is that when the user presses a key input that they are taken to create an account, so yes PrintAccounts() would be used multiple times. The reason for PrintAccounts() being in the Account class is that I'm not quite sure where else I would put it, as I said before I'm new to c# and will need to review my code and see how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account is one Entity and you should not put collection of Account into the same class. Everytime you create new Account, it will reinitialize your collection too.

I have refactored your code as below (Copy paste and try to run)

```
public class Account
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    public void ReadAccount()
    {
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        Username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Email: ");
        UserEmail = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        UserPassword = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class AccountsView
{
    private List<Account> AccountList { get; set; } = new List<Account>();

    public void AddAccount(Account account)
    {
        if (AccountList != null) AccountList.Add(account);
    }

    public void AddAccounts(List<Account> accounts)
    {
        if (AccountList != null) AccountList.AddRange(accounts);
    }

    public void PrintAccounts()
    {
        foreach (Account eachAccount in AccountList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Username: {eachAccount.Username}, UserEmail: {eachAccount.UserEmail}, UserPassword: {eachAccount.UserPassword}");
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this class as

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AccountsView accountsView = new AccountsView();
    //First Account
    Account account = new Account();
    account.ReadAccount();
    accountsView.AddAccount(account);
    //Second Account
    account = new Account();
    account.ReadAccount();
    accountsView.AddAccount(account);
    accountsView.PrintAccounts();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call PrintAccounts() each time new instance will be generated so old value will not be retained.you have to use loop statement in  PrintAccounts(),so that you can add new users.

```
public class Account
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    public string name;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintAccounts();
    }
    static void PrintAccounts()
    {
        AccountView Accounts = new AccountView()
        {
            AccountList = new List<Account>()
        };
      var flag = true;
      While(flag)
      {
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        string userNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Email: ");
        string userEmailInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string userPasswordInput = Console.ReadLine();

        var AccName = new Account
        {
            Username = userNameInput,
            UserEmail = userEmailInput,
            UserPassword = userPasswordInput
        };

       

        Accounts.AccountList.Add(AccName);
        Console.Write("Add more press 1..To exit press any other key");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if(input!="1")
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        }//while end here
        foreach (var Account in Accounts.AccountList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}, UserEmail: {1}, UserPassword: ${2}", Account.Username, Account.UserEmail, Account.UserPassword);
        }
    }
}
public class AccountView
{
    public List<Account> AccountList { get; set; }
}
```

}